# How do I disable automatic save after refactoring in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, autosave

When I ran the Inline and Extract Local Variable refactorings, Eclipse saved my file immediately after.  Also, Undoing/Redoing these refactorings resaved the file each time.  How can I disable this behavior?

Secondary question:  Running Extract Method *didn’t* automatically save the file.   Why the inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 0):

To disable it, you could check if it is caused by having both *Build automatically* and *Save automatically before build* enabled in the preferences (General > Workspace). No idea about the second question.

Comment: No, neither of these options controls what I'm concerned with.  I toggled the former and tested, and the latter was unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the question is why would you not want eclipse to save it? In my case, i didn't want eclipse to save my changes because i was running Tomcat in eclipse and it reloaded the application after each refactoring (i was changing the code as i was debugging it) and i just wanted it to continue executing with the previous code. The solution was to just configure the Publishing section of Tomcat to not publish automatically.